# My little bug in my code

Tags: java

So,I was trying to make a little 'main menu' for my little game.
I have simple things like "Start,instructions,credits" in my main menu.
So my problem is my code works perfectly,but when i want to choose 'instructions' or 'credits' again,my code works without no input.Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Testalani {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menu = "";
        System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
        System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
        System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
        System.out.print(">");
        menu = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(menu.equals("Bilgiler")) {       
            System.out.println("Oyun metin-bazlı bir kısa oyundur.");
            System.out.println("Oyun sırasında '>' işareti görürseniz bilin ki sizden bir girdi bekleniyordur.");
            System.out.println("Oyun sırasında genellikle iki şık olur ve birini seçmeniz istenir.");
            System.out.println("Şıklar büyük harflerle yazılmıştır.");
            System.out.println("Bir şık yazacağınız zaman ilk harfi büyük olacak şekilde yazın.");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Menüye dönmek için 'Geri' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Geri")) {   
            System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");  
            System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
            System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
            System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Jenerik")) {
            System.out.println("Yapımcı: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.println("Senaryo: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.println("Yazılım: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.print(">");
            System.out.println("Menüye dönmek için 'Geri' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Geri")) {   
            System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");  
            System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
            System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
            System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So,I tried things i got on my mind but they didn't work.What should i do?

FYI:'Bilgiler' means 'Instructions' , 'Jenerik' means 'Credits'.

Comment: You have no loop, right?

Comment: Yep,only if statements.

Comment: Put everything a a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you solving your problem. So please: provide ALL english input. Instead of putting up source code in Turkish (?) - and asking **us** to the translation work. Honestly: I find that idea almost rude. Do you really expect us to scroll up and down all the time to figure what is going on?

Comment: Please reduce this code to ***minimal*** example, which still will be ***complete*** (so we could copy-paste and run it on our computers without modifying it) and will allow us to ***reproduce*** your problem. More info at [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Professor901 said:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(true) {        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String menu = "";
        System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
        System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
        System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
        System.out.print(">");
        menu = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(menu.equals("Bilgiler")) {       
            System.out.println("Oyun metin-bazlı bir kısa oyundur.");
            System.out.println("Oyun sırasında '>' işareti görürseniz bilin ki sizden bir girdi bekleniyordur.");
            System.out.println("Oyun sırasında genellikle iki şık olur ve birini seçmeniz istenir.");
            System.out.println("Şıklar büyük harflerle yazılmıştır.");
            System.out.println("Bir şık yazacağınız zaman ilk harfi büyük olacak şekilde yazın.");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Menüye dönmek için 'Geri' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Geri")) {   
            System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");  
            System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
            System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
            System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Jenerik")) {
            System.out.println("Yapımcı: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.println("Senaryo: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.println("Yazılım: Uğur Can Aydın");
            System.out.print(">");
            System.out.println("Menüye dönmek için 'Geri' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        if(menu.equals("Geri")) {   
            System.out.println("Uğur Can'ın mini oyununa hoşgeldiniz!!!");  
            System.out.println("Başlamak için 'Başla'.");
            System.out.println("Oyun öncesi bilgiler için 'Bilgiler'.");
            System.out.println("Jenerik için 'Jenerik' yazınız.");
            System.out.print(">");
            menu = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I gotta admit,i'm pretty stupid about things like this.But REALLY thank you for your support.